# Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com

Tags: email, laravel-5

I want to send emails to the user when it login successfully.but after clicking on the submit button,getting error like this:

```
Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]
```

please help me to get this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your .env use the following:
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
It will work immediately.

If u want your gmail drive to get work, try to setup 2 factor auth